# Does Chrome cache sass includes?

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, sass

If I have 2 files:

style1.min.css - which comes from a .scss file that looks like this:

@import 'base';
@import 'style';

style2.min.css - also from a .scss file that looks like this:

@import 'base';

If a viewer loads a page with style1.min.css and then goes to a page with style2.min.css, will _base.scss be loaded twice? Or is Chrome able to detect and cache that?

Answer (score 0):

SASS files must be compiled to CSS.
So if you have a file.css which includes .sass files, you are doing it wrong.

anyway, the browser cache depends on the response header from the server. You can inspect the response header on network panel on your browser.
Look for the key "expires".

Answer (score 0):

Sass files work by getting compiled to CSS on the server.  Importantly, the @import directive ensures that then entirety of the imported sass file gets compiled into the css file, which means if you have muliple css files that import the same base, the parts imported from base will be duplicated.

The browser knows nothing about sass and only sees the compiled css files.  So while those compiled css files may be cached, the "base" part from style1 would still be "reloaded" from the server when a request for style2 is made (and vice-versa).

Comment: just for clarity, if sourcemaps are added chrome at least can tell which .scss include a style comes from:

https://robots.thoughtbot.com/sass-source-maps-chrome-magic

so for example, on my site clicking to inspect an element it shows it coming from _main.scss and then the .css in the sources

Comment: That is a development environment plug-in which, from the looks of it, requires a fair amount of setup to get working.  The whole point of it is to catch relevant css requests and override them by pointing to (presumably local) resources.  That is a completely different situation from a normal user accessing the site, and one for which the very concept of caching has gone out the window.